# How can I count how many lowercase, uppercase and other characters I have in my string properly?

Tags: c#, uppercase, lowercase

My code here represents the counting of all lowercase and uppercase letter, but I'm having trouble counting all other characters. Other characters consist of spaces and symbols like '!@$^%$'. Anything that isn't lowercase or uppercase refers to other.

However, my problem is that my other is counting uppercase and I can't seem to work the code out.

I do not know where I'm going wrong so any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a sentence: ");
string sentence = Console.ReadLine();
int countUpper = 0, countLower=0, countOther=0, i;



        for (i = 0; i < sentence.Length;i++ )
        {
            if (char.IsUpper(sentence[i])) countUpper++;
            if (char.IsLower(sentence[i])) countLower++;
            if (!(char.IsLower(sentence[i]) || (!(char.IsUpper(sentence[i]))))) countOther++;

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Lower: " + countLower);
        Console.WriteLine("Upper: " + countUpper);
        Console.WriteLine("Other: " + countOther);
```

Comment: Change `||` with `&&`.

Comment: `if (! ((char.IsLower(sentence[i]) || (char.IsUpper(sentence[i]) )))`

Comment: Consider also using `foreach(char character in sentence) { if (char.IsUpper(character)) ... `  You wish to operate on a set of *characters*, so there's no need to involve all the mechanisms of *indexers*.

Answer (score 5):

Try using `if` / `else if` / `else` instead:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a sentence: ");
string sentence = Console.ReadLine();
int countUpper = 0, countLower=0, countOther=0, i;



        for (i = 0; i < sentence.Length;i++ )
        {
            if (char.IsUpper(sentence[i])) countUpper++;
            else if (char.IsLower(sentence[i])) countLower++;
            else countOther++;

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Lower: " + countLower);
        Console.WriteLine("Upper: " + countUpper);
        Console.WriteLine("Other: " + countOther);
```

Comment: I like this better than fixing the logic as it reduces the number of calls to `IsUpper` and `IsLower`.  No idea why it got a downvote.

Answer (score 2):

To count specific characters, simple `Regex` can be used instead analyzing char by char:

```
string sentence = "testTESTING@,";
int countLower = Regex.Matches(sentence, @"\p{Ll}").Count;
int countUpper = Regex.Matches(sentence, @"\p{Lu}").Count;
int countOther = Regex.Matches(sentence, @"\W").Count;

// \p{category} - In that Unicode category
// category = Lu - Letter, uppercase
// category = Ll - letter, lowercase
// \W = non word character
```

Simple specification *".Net framework regular expressions quick reference"* can be downloaded from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43119

Answer (score -1):

I think `countOther` would just be `string.Length - countUpper - countLower`.

Comment: This is going to depend on the culture.  As much as you may want it to be true, it's not necessarily true.

Comment: then I would just make this change in his current code if (!(char.IsLower(sentence[i]) && (!(char.IsUpper(sentence[i]))))) countOther++; However i'm not able to think of the cultural influences you're talking about can you give an example?